# php unable to use bootstrap when include() is used

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've below HTML code which I intend to use with index.php file but there seems a problem.

```
<!-- nav bar -->
<nav id="top">
<nav class="navbar navbar-xs navbar-custom"> 
  <div class="container-fluid" >

        <div  class="nav pull-right">
        <font face="bebas">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#"> 123456789 </a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" title="My Account" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                      </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="wishlist-total" title="Wish List (0)"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Wish List (0)</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Shopping Cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shopping Cart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Checkout"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Checkout</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</nav>

<!-- searchbar and logo -->

<header id="margin">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="logo">
                    <center> <span class="tab-space"></span> <a href="J:\lawn\home\home2.htm"><img src="J:\lawn\home\artwork\lawn.png" height="42px" /></a>
                  </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
       <div id="search" class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" border-rad>
          <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" style="border-radius: 0;">Search</button>
          </span>
       </div>      
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </font>
 </header>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>

<title> experiment ground </title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1"> omitted to remove unresponsiveness of columns -->

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">



<link href="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\cutom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<?php include('includes\header.html'); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

i want an output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrJNX.png) but all i am getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K28B5.png).
is it a problem with using bootstrap or something else entirely.
my main purpose is to use include() feature of PHP to make my code minimal. is there any other way I can include headers or footers templates or codes to a PHP page? 
thank you!

Comment: Please ensure that the bootstrap files path are correct. Try the link href url in your browser and confirm the files are placed correctly

Comment: You have local file paths (J:\foo\bar) rather than http paths for your bootstrap assets.  These don't look quite right.

Comment: This has to be a filepath issue.

Comment: file paths were correct, but placing bootstrap files in project directory and updating them, of course somehow made it all worked, i don't know why exactly that should happen and later not, but it works, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Link jQuery before you include Bootstrap

```
<link href="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\cutom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"</script>  
<script src="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) open your Developer Tools (F12)

2) refresh page

3) check "console" tab

I think, you'll find answers in console.
Anyway, change your paths to relative (assuming file index.php at one tree level with bootstrap directory):

```
href="bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css"
```

Instead of:

```
href="J:\bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.6-dist\css\bootstrap.min.css"
```

And do it for all files, or just connect it from CDN - it will be great ;)

Answer (score 1):

Call jquery.min.js **before** bootstrap.min.js

The script bootstrap.min.js uses jQuery plug-in in most actions.

Also, check if the files are actually in the path described. It is highly recommended that you call the files from the main project directory.

Comment: i copied bootstrap files in the project directory and it works like a charm, thank you, you saved my day